# PostgreSQL and pgadmin3.exe

Tags: postgresql, window

I am trying to start playing with postgres and found a very strange thing, I created a table using pgadminIII named testtable and added couple of column then I wrote following query in query editor

```
SELECT * from testtable;
```

it responded no table found with such name, then after that I tried

```
select * from "testtable"
```

with quotes(later one) it worked, then I dropped the table and created the table using script editor, with same name making it sure no quotes are around the name, then both query started working, I can't understand stand what that exactly mean, even if I write "teablename" in create table statement quotes shouldn't become the part of the table name.

Also, how can I make sure while using pgAdmin graphical user interface that all object get created without quote (of course if above problem because of that)?

**Update: Environment Info**

> OS => Windows Server 2008 x64,  Postgres => 9.0.3-2 x64,  pgAdmin => >
>   Version 1.12.2 (March 22, 2011, rev:>
>   REL-1_12_2)

Comment: What version of pgadmin are you on and what OS are you running it on?  Also can you include your create table statement?

Comment: OS => Windows Server 2008 x64, Postgres => 9.0.3-2 x64, pgAdmin => Version 1.12.2 (March 22, 2011, rev: REL-1_12_2)

Answer (score 1):

Did you use the new table dialog the first time? You shouldn't use quotes in the dialog as pgAdmin will insert all necessary quotes.

**Edit**
I discovered something today what is a little weird and might explain what happened to you.

When you do not quote a table name the table name it is converted to lowercase. So if you do

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable ( ... );
```

Your table will be called testtable
What happens when you start to query the table is this:

```
SELECT * FROM TestTable; -- succeeds looks for testtable
SELECT * FROM testtable; -- succeeds
SELECT * FROM "TestTable"; -- fails because case doesn't match
```

Now if you had done:

```
CREATE TABLE "TestTable" ( ... );
```

Your table would actually be called TestTable with the case preserved and the result is

```
SELECT * FROM TestTable; -- fails looks for testtable
SELECT * FROM testtable; -- fails
SELECT * FROM "TestTable"; -- succeeds
```

Comment: i am not adding quotes myself, in dialogue.